# Using gsub to regroup education, but error occurs

Tags: r, class, group-by, grouping, rename

I would like to regroup the "education class". For example, I want to group before high school together. I assign "beforeHS", but the output is not what I expect.

original output:

```
summary(data$education)
         11th       5th-6th       7th-8th           9th    Assoc-acdm     Assoc-voc 
         1175           333           646           514          1067          1382 
    Bachelors     Doctorate       HS-grad       Masters     Preschool   Prof-school 
         5354           413         10501          1723            51           576 
 Some-college          12th      beforeHS       Unknown 
         7291           168           433           933
```

Below, I attempted to use gsub() function.

```
###combine high school below or 12th together 
data$education <-gsub('^12th', 'beforeHS', data$education)
data$education <-gsub('^10th', 'beforeHS', data$education)
data$education <-gsub('^11th', 'beforeHS', data$education)
data$education <-gsub('^1st-4th', 'beforeHS', data$education)
data$education <-gsub('^5th-6th', 'beforeHS', data$education)
data$education <-gsub('^7th-8th', 'beforeHS', data$education)
data$education <-gsub('^9th', 'beforeHS', data$education)
data$education <-gsub('^Preschool', 'beforeHS', data$education)
data$education<-as.factor(data$education)
```

And this outputs:

```
summary(data$education) 
         11th       5th-6th       7th-8th           9th    Assoc-acdm     Assoc-voc 
         1175           333           646           514          1067          1382 
      Bachelors     Doctorate       HS-grad       Masters     Preschool   Prof-school 
         5354           413         10501          1723            51           576 
     Some-college      beforeHS       Unknown 
         7291           601           933
```

I did see "beforeHS", but but all grades < k12 are there still there. And it seems to be the data is messed up. Could you let me know if I missed anything? Thank you!

Comment: You may need to provide a reproducible example. I see no reason why your code should not work (looks like only the first line has and nothing else). Trying to run similar code on a copy of the `iris` dataset, for example, works. (This is aside from the fact that there are easier ways to do what you are doing; given that you are essentially doing whole-string exact matching, `gsub` isn't really necessary here)

Comment: My guess is that your `$education` has leading whitespace: typically the width of these columns is one more than the widest string in the bunch. Since the widest is 12 characters but the columns appear to be spaced by 14, that suggests at least one leading space on at least the longest string ... and if there's leading whitespace on one, check all of them. Or just run `data$education <- trimws(data$education)` and try your `gsub`s again.

Comment: Thank you so much. There exists leading space and I'm able to regroup after trimming space.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the values that you want to turn to `"beforeHS"` either start with number ("1st", "5th", "11th") or is "Preschool". We can create a pattern to detect this and replace those values with `"beforeHS"`.

```
data$education[grepl("^\\d|Preschool", data$education)] <- "beforeHS"
```